# nltk too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, nltk

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import brown

brown_tagged_sents = brown.tagged_sents(categories='news')
((x[1],y[1],z[0],z[1])
    for sent in brown_tagged_sents
    for x,y,z in nltk.trigrams(sent))
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
    ((x[1],y[1],z[0],z[1])
    for sent in brown_tagged_sents
    for x,y,z in nltk.trigrams(sent))
)
```

The code above will occur:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/Users/shike/Desktop/textprocess/nltktest.py", line 10, in <module>  
    for sent in brown_tagged_sents  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/probability.py", line  
 1803, in __init__  
    for (cond, sample) in cond_samples:  
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

The **list comprehension**

```
((x[1],y[1],z[0],z[1])
    for sent in brown_tagged_sents
    for x,y,z in nltk.trigrams(sent))
```

can work well alone, but something wrong happens when it's used as a parameter. I still don't know why. All the code was tested in Python3.

Answer (score 1):

The initializer `nltk.ConditionalFreqDist()` expect for two parameters, condition and sample. So, `(x[1],y[1],z[0],z[1])` need to be written as `((x[1],y[1],z[0]),z[1])`.

Answer (score 0):

`nltk.ConditionalFreqDist` expects an iterable of two element tuples like `(condition, sample)`. But you are passing an iterable of 4-element tuples `(x[1],y[1],z[0],z[1])`.

You might need to look into the [documentation](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html) and [implementation](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/probability.html#ConditionalFreqDist) of 
that class.